# NPE in generic array with List interface

Tags: java, list, generics

This particular line in a method throws an NPE, and I'm stuck on it for two days:

```
List<Peak>[] peaks = (List<Peak>[]) new ArrayList[samples.length/Spectra.spectraInterval];
```

The method in which the line occurs is:

```
public static List<Peak>[] getPeaks(AudioClip clip) {
    double[] samples = clip.getSamples();
    List<Peak>[] peaks = (List<Peak>[]) new ArrayList[samples.length/Spectra.spectraInterval];
    peaks[0] = new ArrayList<Peak>();
    for (int i = 1; i < peaks.length; i++) {
        Spectra s = new Spectra(i, Arrays.copyOfRange(
                samples, 
                i*Spectra.spectraInterval - Spectra.samplesPerSpectra/2, 
                i*Spectra.spectraInterval + Spectra.samplesPerSpectra/2
                ));

        peaks[i] = s.getPeaks();
        //System.out.println(peaks[i]);
    }return peaks;


}
```

This method is part of a class, Extractor that extracts the difference in time required for two peaks to get paired into a Probe. My question is:

1. Is the Peak object creation wrong? or the conversion to ArrayList wrong?
2. Is the NPE due to samples.length (declared in another class) returning null?

Pl help. I am new to Java, just working my way around a Shazam-like code that has an audio file input - trying to replace that with a mic input in a different class.

Comment: I would check that `samples` is not `null` in your debugger.

Comment: Spectra.spectraInterval is a primitive or a wrapper ? A null wrapper can throw a NPE too. PS : no need to cast the array list, even for array)

Comment: Post an [MCVE] : post the bare minimum to show your issue. 
(Writing a minimal case is a good debugging technique. In doing so you are likely to solve your problem.)

Comment: 'samples' is null that's why NPE occurs 

'List<Peak>[] peaks = (List<Peak>[]) new ArrayList[samples.length/Spectra.spectraInterval];'

Answer (score 0):

Try investigate that using some logs (maybe samples is null?):

```
System.out.println("samples = " + samples + ", interval = " + Spectra.spectraInterval);  
List<Peak>[] peaks = (List<Peak>[]) new ArrayList[samples.length/Spectra.spectraInterval];
```

Comment: Samples did indeed return null. I will have to check the mic input code for the samples.

Answer (score 0):

An NPE is raised, if something gets called on an object, whose value is `null`. (methods, attributes).

In your case there are two such calls in this line:
`samples.length` and `Spectra.spectraInterval`.

`Spectra.spectraInterval` seems to be a static call, which will not raise an NPE, even if the value of `spectraInterval` is `null`. (Because it's absolutely legit to return null values.)

The `samples` array on the other hand comes from the `AudioClip`. Check if there is a value present and handle it, if not.

E.g.,

```
public static List<Peak>[] getPeaks(AudioClip clip) {
    double[] samples = clip.getSamples();

    if(samples == null || samples.length == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList().toArray();
    }

    List<Peak>[] peaks = (List<Peak>[]) new     ArrayList[samples.length/Spectra.spectraInterval];
    peaks[0] = new ArrayList<Peak>();
    for (int i = 1; i < peaks.length; i++) {
        Spectra s = new Spectra(i, Arrays.copyOfRange(
                samples, 
                i*Spectra.spectraInterval -     Spectra.samplesPerSpectra/2, 
                i*Spectra.spectraInterval +     Spectra.samplesPerSpectra/2
                ));

        peaks[i] = s.getPeaks();
        //System.out.println(peaks[i]);
    }
    return peaks;
}
```

Comment: Samples returned null. Will check the AudioClip class like you mentioned.